# How to pass a parameter from action filter to a controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to make a custom authentication filter. If everything succeeds, it should return the user. But, in the controller, I need it again to find the user, but this would be inefficient to search for him once again in the database. I want to reuse the information gained in the `ActionFilter`. This is the pseudocode that shows exactly what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class AuthenticateAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public async override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // some code here...
        var user = // some code...

        if (user == null)
        {
            // error, not authenticated
        }

        // yes! authentication succeeded! now we have found the user, it would be clever to pass
        // it to the controller method so that it does not have to look it up once again in the database
        parameters.Add("userFound", user);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I would like then to access it in the controller method, no matter how. For example like this:

```
parameters["userFound"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: If he's an authenticated user, you can access he through `HttpContextBase.User` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontextbase.user(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

In `ActionExecutingContext` you have full access to controller and request then you have many places you can put your parameter, just to mention few:

- `context.Controller.ViewBag`, it's also accessible in your view.
- context.Controller.ViewData, it's also accessible in your view.
- `context.HttpContext.Session`, if you're using session.

Remember that `ActionExecutingContext` derives from `ControllerContext` and `ControllerContext` is accessible everywhere in your controller.

However I'd avoid this because it's (at least to me) little bit strange. Your controller will take a different action according to that parameter (not much different than a check on `User.IsAuthenticated`) then what I would really do is to redirect to a **differenct** action method, in your action filter:

```
if (user == null) // not authenticated
{
    var data = context.HttpContext.Request.RequestContext.RouteData;
    var currentAction = data.GetRequiredString("action");
    var currentController = data.GetRequiredString("controller");

    context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
        new RouteValueDictionary 
        { 
            { "controller", currentController }, 
            { "action", currentAction + "_NotAuthenticated" } 
    });
}
```